# Django method to download and store files

Tags: python, django, storage, django-staticfiles

Is there a way to download files by an app's method and store in a folder like "/media/" (relative path in django app) that can be later accessed by staticfiles?

Answer (score 0):

For storing your media files in a folder like `/media`, you can check this out since you are new to django.

[Tango with Django Tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/templates_static.html)

This link is about setting the static and media files' directory. But if you feel like you don't understand them, Just start from the beginning.

For downloading a file, I can give you a small example.

```
import requests
def download_file(self,link):
    content = requests.get(link).content
    f = open('filename', 'wb')
    f.write(content)
    f.flush()
    f.close()
```

But if you don't know the basic concepts of Django, I'd recomment you to go with Tango with Django first.

Comment: The download part is OK, but my problem is the following:
* when I use STATIC_URL = '/static/' than it means that the files are at myproj/app/static/app/file.ext
* and when I use MEDIA_URL = '/media/' it won't use either myproj/media nor myproj/app/media/app/file.ext

Why is this, and is there an other way instead of MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media') ?